# Firebase Hosting for AngularJS APP + PHP Backend

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, hosting, firebase-hosting

newb hosting question here:

I'm used to building angular apps + firebase then just simply hosting on firebase. However, I needed some PHP functionality to communicate with Amazon's Seller Central API.. Locally during development I run a WAMP server for the PHP.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can host the PHP scripts? Should I just host the whole thing on a goDaddy linux server or is there a way I can use Firebase Hosting + Google Cloud Service .. or maybe Heroku.

Any Help, thank you. Sorry it this is a dumb Q.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Hosting is for hosting and serving static assets (html, css, js) only.

According to Firebase Hosting [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/):

> With Hosting, you can quickly and easily deploy web apps and static
>   content to a global content-delivery network (CDN) with a single
>   command.

However, with that said, you could instead use Firebase Functions and leverage on API endpoints and HTTP triggers to write and execute your backend code.

Note that if you want to communicate from Firebase Functions to a 3rd party site, in your case Amazon APIs, you will have to enable billing. Functions are free to use if you're communicating within any of Google's services.